# Strategy pattern in Symfony2

Tags: php, design-patterns, symfony

I'm trying to build simple service for rendering various types of pages. Basic concept is having something like:

```
$somePageType = new PageType(...);
$this->get('page.service')->render($somePagetype);
```

...which would be designed as [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Page types would implement interface with `render` method and `page.service` would call it. The problem is I'd like to use Doctrine in page type classes. What are my options here? I'd like to avoid creating service for each of these classes. Is that even possible? Is it possible to make them container aware without being services? Possibly, in the future, some page type might need something more than only Doctrine, so I need to keep in mind also that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `PageType` is an example of a strategy class. In that case, you could inject the dependencies by the `page.service` and you wouldn't need to define the strategies as services.

Each strategy probably depends on different objects and therefore I guess you could make them `ContainerAware`. Here's an example how to do it

```
// This is the page.service class
class MyPageService {

    public function render(PageTypeInterface $page_type) {
        $page_type->setContainer($this->container);

        // do stuff
    }
}

// This is the type strategy
class MyStrategyType extends ContainerAware implements PageTypeInterface {
    // you can access the container after MyPageService has injected it.
}
```

So basically each strategy would extend [`ContainerAware`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.php) and the `page.service` would inject the container.

---

**EDIT**

If all of your strategies are dependant on the same services, I'd inject them instead of the whole container.

```
class MyPageService {

    public function render(PageTypeInterface $page_type) {
        $page_type->setService($this->container->get('my_service'));

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's no good to pass the container around. If his object requires doctrine, he should require it by adding a parameter in constructor for doctrine object.

Comment: @meze of course, but what if every strategy has different dependencies. This would be the only way. However, I would personally define all of the strategies as services actually.

Comment: and how would you test your strategies? reuse in another project without symfony?

Comment: @meze Valid point. If I made my strategies container aware then testing and reuse is indeed difficult. That's why I said I'd make them all services, which would mean passing the dependencies either by the constructor or setters. Both testing and code reuse wouldn't be a problem then.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know if I'll need different services in other strategies. It's certainly possible and I wanna be prepared for it. So declaring each strategy as service would be probably the best way to do it. It only annoys me that using service just adds more (unnecessary) work to such simple thing. But I guess I don't have many choices here.

Answer (score 3):

Services are exactly what you want here. Being able to inject the dependencies for the particular strategy in question. Then injecting the particular strategy into the controller (could also be a dynamic renderer that chooses the strategy at runtime).

ContainerAware is a really bad practice, it couples the object in question to **all** of the services in the container. Thus, I'd strongly recommend avoiding it.